# SQL Server : copy row and Insert into to the same table but with a different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would just like to copy a specific `LOAD_NO` from a table called `LOADS` and insert it back into the same `LOADS` table but without using the old `LOAD_NO` (aka `ID`)....

The tables name is `LOADS`.

1. I would like to copy a specific row and insert it into the table but without needing to specify all of the fields (because the table has a lot of fields)
2. I need to exclude the field named: `LOAD_NO`
3. Then delete the old row

I tried something like this:

I cloned the `LOADS` table without cloning the data and I named that table `LOADS_TempTable` and added the identity of `LOAD_NO` seed start at: `11600`

```
SELECT * 
INTO LOADS_TempTable 
FROM LOADS WHERE LOAD_NO = 200;

ALTER TABLE LOADS_TempTable DROP COLUMN LOAD_NO;

INSERT INTO LOADS 
   SELECT * 
   FROM LOADS_TempTable;

DELETE FROM LOADS 
WHERE LOAD_NO = 200;
```

Here is how the column `LOAD_NO` in the table `LOADS` looks:

[image]

The error I get says the following:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'LOADS' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I tried to add:

```
set identity_insert LOADS OFF
GO
```

and also

```
set identity_insert LOADS ON
GO
```

I always get the same error.

THANKS FOR ANY HELP :)

Comment: Just omit the identity column from the insert column list and value list.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens He tried that. That's what the ALTER TABLE was about.

Comment: Best bet is probably going to be to build your column list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `LOAD_NO` is an **identity** column, you should not be specifying a value for it when inserting. So you need to modify our `INSERT` statement to **not** include the `LOAD_NO` column - something like this:

```
INSERT INTO LOADS(col1, col2, ..., colN)  -- all columns *EXCEPT* LOAD_NO
   SELECT col1, col2, ...., colN          -- all columns *EXCEPT* LOAD_NO 
   FROM LOADS_TempTable;
```

SQL Server will automatically assign a new `LOAD_NO` to the row you're inserting - after all, that's the *job* of the **identity** column!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set identity_insert LOADS ON
Update LOADS set Load_No = (select max(load_no) + 1 from loads) where load_no = 200
set identity_insert LOADS OFF
```

You probably also want to wrap that in a transaction.

Comment: Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot update identity column 'LOAD_NO'.

Answer (score 1):

It:

```
INSERT INTO LOADS 
SELECT * --now begins from the second column, you drop the first column.
FROM LOADS_TempTable;
```

is the same:

```
INSERT INTO LOADS VALUES(Load_No, second_colum, n_column)
SELECT second_colum, n_column
FROM LOADS_TempTable;
```

you're trying to insert a second_column value into a first_column (Load_No) so you get error.

Solution:

```
INSERT INTO LOADS VALUES(second_colum, n_column)
SELECT * -- or: SELECT second_colum, n_column 
FROM LOADS_TempTable;
```